# Exception when Calling AlertBuilder from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alert, builder

I've a main activity.

In this I've defined a function for use AlertBuilder passing a stringId from resource file.

I'm trying to use this for showing an error when not enough space left on disk, from my AsyncTask.

But when calling context.showAlert i got a runtime exception

> 09-09 14:41:44.812: E/Background(8963): Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the UI (as in this call) from one of the function that are called on the main thread, not in the background.

E.g. from one of the following:

- onProgressUpdate
- onPostExecute

Comment: so, if I want to comunicate to user for "no space left on disk", but this is caught by try..catch .. how can do this ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, I was not around my computer. You can call `publishProgress` from inside a try-catch block as well, so it should not be a problem. Anyway, if my post still didn't answer your question, you don't have to accept it.

Comment: Your answer is right, i'd like only some more infos. So i understand that the trick is expand code into onProgressUpdate to handle this case, it was just the trick I was looking for. So, your answer, now, is complete. Thanks